# How do I make a CiviEvent accessible to the public?

Tags: civievent

After I create an event in CIVI where does it then go?  How can outsiders find out event?
I participated in a class the other day and was successful at the application but now that I have created the event I am unsure how to find it and how others can find it to register.  Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

By default CiviCRM events aren't publicised online. To make the event public you need to tick the box for online event registration.

See the user guide for more details: [Online event registration](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/stable/events/online-event-registration/)

[image]